# Regex should Replace the Contents in xml file, but not the tag name

Tags: c#, regex

Please see the code below:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(doc.OuterXml, "\\b" + l_sOldvalue + "\\b");
if ((match.Success) && (l_bflag))
{
    string pattern = "\\b" + l_sOldvalue + "\\b";
    string l_sChangexml = Regex.Replace(doc.OuterXml, pattern, l_sNewValue);
    doc.LoadXml(l_sChangexml);
}
```

Here I'm using RegEx Match and Replace, but it replaces the tag names also. For me the tag name should not be replaced.

doc.outerxml --> contains complete xml file

Can any one please solve this?

Comment: Please check the best answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1).

Comment: I checked but , it is not clear , can you please share the exact regex to me

Comment: They're pointing out that using Regex is the **wrong** tool for the job. There's an entire [Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml(v=vs.110).aspx) dedicated to XML processing in .NET framework.

Comment: I want a solution in regex only , It will be easier for me to process

Comment: Give an example of the xml, before and after.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a "negative lookbehind" in your Regex. E.g. if you want to make sure that you don't catch a tag like `<blafasel>` or `</blafasel>`, but all occurences of `blafasel` as a single word, use the following pattern:

```
var pattern = @"(?i)(?<![</])\bblafasel\b";
```

Or to use your sample:

```
string pattern = @"(?i)(?<![</])\b" + l_sOldvalue + @"\b";    
Match match = Regex.Match(doc.OuterXml, pattern);

if ((match.Success) && (l_bflag))
{
    string l_sChangexml = Regex.Replace(doc.OuterXml, pattern, l_sNewValue);
    doc.LoadXml(l_sChangexml);
}
```

Please show a sample of your XML the next time, that would make it easier.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much , now it is worked for me , once again big thanks :)

Comment: Can you please explain the regular expression used below               @"(?i)(?<![</])\bblafasel\b";

Comment: It says 
`(?i)` regexengine, watch out:
`(?<!` I don't want to see left from my searchstring the following
`[</]` characters
`\bblafasel\b` and my searchstring is the complete word blafasel.

Comment: Thank you , i would like to learn more examples in regular expression , can you please share me any links to learn more

Comment: The resource that helped me most was the book [Introducing Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920012337.do). Its approach is very good and the samples are quick to understand.

Comment: Thank you , I think we have to but the book , do you have any free dwonloads link ? :)

Comment: Hello , The above example is fine , but can you please update the regex and share me , in which the attribute name also should not be renamed eg : here <tag id="10"></tag>"id" should not be renamed can you please us the solution asap

Comment: @Muller :- can you please help me for the above mentioned comments

Answer (score 0):

hmm - removing all content could be done by removing everything between `>` and `<` or did i miss something? additional to this all tag-attributes have to be removed that can be done by deleting everything between `<charactersToNextWhitespace` and `>`.

may be (not testet it)

```
s/>.*?</></g
s/(<\w+)\W.*?>/\1/g;
```

Comment: I used this regex , It is perfectly working                                                          @"(?i) @"(?i)(?<![</])\b" + l_sOldvalue + @"\b";

Comment: Hello , The above example is fine , but can you please update the regex and share me , in which the attribute name also should not be renamed eg : here <tag id="10"></tag>"id" should not be renamed can you please us the solution asap

Comment: @SakthiRaj i do not completely understand what you want. do you only want the attribute names (eg: `<tag attrib_a attribb_>`) or just or do you want jast to keep the id-attrib inclusive its valu (eg: `<tag id="10">`)? the last one is easy, if the id attribute is always the first attribute.

Comment: Hello, I don't want to change the attribute name eg-"id" , but attribute value can be changed eg-"10", I think we have to modify the following  @"(?i)(?<![</])\b" + l_sOldvalue + @"\b"